# Is this usage of realloc correct? (Trying to increase the size of an array by doubling it's size)

Tags: c, malloc

The problem is that realloc fails every time. I was wondering if I am using it correctly.

```
if (iNum >= ArrSize) {
    ArrSize = ArrSize * 2;
    NumArr = realloc(NumArr, ArrSize * sizeof(int));

    if (NumArr == NULL) {
        printf("Array not reallocated!\n");
        printf("Array size was: %d", ArrSize);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I tried printing the value of the variable ArrSize. The output was:

```
Enter the amount of prime numbers to list: 5
2
3
5
Array not reallocated!
Array size was: 8
```

I was originally increase the size of the array every time it reaches it's limit. So the expected result was the array size being doubled while keeping the existing values of NumArr the same.
So it was not a problem of ArrSize's value being too large or negative in value.

This is the the whole function:

```
int PrimeChecker(int nPrime) {
    size_t ArrSize = nPrime - 1;
    int iFlag, CurPrime;
    int j = 1;
    
    int *NumArr = calloc(ArrSize, sizeof(int)); // Array (Pointer) of flags for filtering non-prime numbers

    if (NumArr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Array not allocated!");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int iNum = 2; CurPrime != nPrime + 1; iNum++) {

        if (NumArr[iNum] != 1) {
            printf("%d\n", iNum);
            CurPrime++;
            iFlag = iNum;

            for (; (iFlag * j) <= nPrime; j++) {
                NumArr[iFlag * j] = 1;
            }
            j = 0;

            if (iNum >= ArrSize) {
                ArrSize = ArrSize * 2;
                NumArr = realloc(NumArr, ArrSize * sizeof(int));

                if (NumArr == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Array not reallocated!\n");
                    printf("Array size was: %d", ArrSize);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(NumArr);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int nPrime; // User input for number of primes to list
    printf("Enter the amount of prime numbers to list: ");
    scanf("%d", &nPrime);
    PrimeChecker(nPrime);
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: As a side-note: Notice that if `realloc()` fails, the old `NumArr` will remain allocated and invariably leak. The way the code is currently written, the original allocation is no longer reachable, as `NumArr` is now `NULL`, and the only (?) pointer to the original allocation is lost.

Comment: I added the whole function to make it more understandable as advised by @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: The posted code is incomplete. You should post complete code that can be compiled and run and which demonstrates the problem; this is the meaning of [mcve]. Why does `PrimeChecker` only return a value when there is an error? It should _always_ return something.

Comment: `CurPrime` is not initialized. `ArrSize` should be formated with `%zu`, not `%d`. `NumArr[iFlag*j] = 1;` sometimes writes to an element beyond those allocated. Fix those problems and the `NumArr[iNum]` issue above and get your code working, and then the `realloc` issue will likely vanish.